# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Al momento de persistir los datos

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jpa

Mi problema radica en que al momento de ejecutar y crear las tablas en mi base de datos me salta este error

```
[EL Info]: 2023-10-22 16:13:57.782--ServerSession(916006772)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.10.v20211216-fe64cd39c3
[EL Warning]: metamodel: 2023-10-22 16:13:58.055--The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: com.back.model.Usuario@2a473074 is not a known Entity type.
```

Revise los datos obtenidos de los componentes y estos se encuentran guardados en sus variables,Revise la sintasis de mis metodos de controlador de clase y el de jpa ytodo se ve bien, revise mi archivo de persistencia y estan agregadas mis dos entidades, no he logrado encontrar el problema, agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Anexo mis clases controladoras con los metodos utilizados,el jframe con los datos de los componentes y mi archivo persistence.

**Controlador del paquete modelo**

```
package com.back.model;

import com.back.persistence.ControladoraPersistencia;


public class Controladora {
    
    //Instanciacion de la controladora de persistencia en la logica
    ControladoraPersistencia controlPersis = new ControladoraPersistencia();
    
    /*
        METODO PARA OBTENER LOS DATOS DEL PAQUETE GUI.
        1.Instanciacion de la clases Usuario
        2.Seteo de los valores obtenidos
        3.Instanciacion de la clase Horario
        4.Seteo de los valores obtenidos
        5.Envio de los objetos del paquete modelo al controlador de persistencia (guardar en base de datos)
    */

    public void guardar(String nombreUsuario, String apellidoUsuario, String documentoUsuario, String cargoUsuario, String password, String jornada, String horario) {
        
        Horario horario1 = new Horario();
        horario1.setJornada(jornada);
        horario1.setHorario(horario);
        
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        usuario.setNombre(nombreUsuario);
        usuario.setApellido(apellidoUsuario);
        usuario.setDocumento(documentoUsuario);
        usuario.setPassword(password);
        usuario.setCargo(cargoUsuario);
        usuario.setHorario(horario1);
        
        controlPersis.guardar(usuario,horario1);
    }
    
}
```

**Controlador de jpa**

```
package com.back.persistence;

import com.back.model.Horario;
import com.back.model.Usuario;


public class ControladoraPersistencia {
    
    //Instanciacion de los controladores de persistencias
    UsuarioJpaController usuarioJpa = new UsuarioJpaController();
    HorarioJpaController horarioJpa = new HorarioJpaController();

    /*
        METODO PARA GUARDAR LOS OBJETOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS
        1.Creacion del usuario en la base de datos
        2.Creacion del horario en la base de datos
    */
    public void guardar(Usuario usuario, Horario horario1) {
        usuarioJpa.create(usuario);
        horarioJpa.create(horario1);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

**Jframe del cual se obtienen los datos de los componentes**

```
package com.back.gui;

import com.back.model.Controladora;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class CargarDatos extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /*
        Instanciaciones:
        1.Instanciacion de la clase controladora
        2.Instanciacion de la Interfaz que contiene las variables globales
    */
    Controladora control = new Controladora();
    Login login = new Login();
    
    /*
        Variables para almacenar los datos de componentes anteriores
    */
    private String nombreUsuario;
    private String apellidoUsuario;
    private String documentoUsuario;
    private String cargoUsuario;
    private String documentoIngreso = login.documentoIngreso;
    private String password = login.password;
    
    //Constructo de la clase Cargar 
    public CargarDatos() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    
    /*
        METODO PARA OBTENER Y GUARDAR LOS DATOS DE LA INTERFAZ NUEVOINGRESO EN VARIABLES GLOBALES
    */
    public void obtenerDatosNuevoIngreso ( String nombreUsuario, String apellidoUsuario,String documentoUsuario, String cargoUsuario){
        
        this.nombreUsuario = nombreUsuario;
        this.apellidoUsuario = apellidoUsuario;
        this.documentoUsuario = documentoUsuario;
        this.cargoUsuario = cargoUsuario;
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnGuardar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnLimpiar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cmbJornada = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        dcFechaHora = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
        txtApellido = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtDocumento = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtNombre = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtCargo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtDocumentoIngreso = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtContraseña = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtJornada = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txthorario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(840, 560));
        jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 3, 48)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("Tere Food");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 10, -1, -1));

        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/theresfoodlogo.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(490, 290, -1, -1));

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel4.setText("Horario");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 210, -1, -1));

        btnGuardar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/disc-2029826_640.png"))); // NOI18N
        btnGuardar.setText("Guardar");
        btnGuardar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnGuardarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(btnGuardar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 390, 110, 50));

        btnLimpiar.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        btnLimpiar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/wipe-97583_640.png"))); // NOI18N
        btnLimpiar.setText("Limpiar");
        btnLimpiar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnLimpiarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(btnLimpiar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(220, 390, -1, -1));

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel7.setText("Jornada");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 140, -1, -1));

        cmbJornada.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "-", "Entrada", "Salida" }));
        jPanel1.add(cmbJornada, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(160, 140, 110, 30));

        dcFechaHora.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
        jPanel1.add(dcFechaHora, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(160, 210, 140, 30));

        txtApellido.setEditable(false);
        jPanel1.add(txtApellido, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(520, 30, 110, -1));

        txtDocumento.setEditable(false);
        jPanel1.add(txtDocumento, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(690, 30, 110, -1));

        txtNombre.setEditable(false);
        jPanel1.add(txtNombre, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(380, 30, 110, -1));

        txtCargo.setEditable(false);
        jPanel1.add(txtCargo, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(370, 90, 110, -1));

        txtDocumentoIngreso.setEditable(false);
        jPanel1.add(txtDocumentoIngreso, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(530, 90, 110, -1));

        txtContraseña.setEditable(false);
        jPanel1.add(txtContraseña, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(690, 90, 110, -1));

        txtJornada.setEditable(false);
        jPanel1.add(txtJornada, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(370, 150, 110, -1));

        txthorario.setEditable(false);
        jPanel1.add(txthorario, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(530, 140, 110, -1));

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/fondo.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 840, 560));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    
    //Metodo para limpiar componentes
    private void btnLimpiarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        cmbJornada.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }                                          

    /*
        METODO PARA GUARDAR DATOS OBTENIDOS
        1.Creacion de variables auxiliares para guardar datos de jornada y horario
        2.Seteo de los componenete auxiliares para mostrar los datos obtenidos
        3.Uso del objeto controlador y su metodo guardar, para enviar valores
        4.Mensaje en pantala para verificar el guardado de datos
    */
    private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        String jornada = (String) cmbJornada.getSelectedItem();
        String horario;
        //java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm");
        horario = f.format(dcFechaHora.getDate());
        txtNombre.setText(nombreUsuario);
        txtApellido.setText(apellidoUsuario);
        txtDocumento.setText(documentoUsuario);
        txtCargo.setText(cargoUsuario);
        txtJornada.setText(jornada);
        txthorario.setText(horario);
        txtDocumentoIngreso.setText(documentoIngreso);
        txtContraseña.setText(password);
        
        control.guardar(nombreUsuario,apellidoUsuario,documentoUsuario,cargoUsuario,password,jornada,horario);
        
        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Los Datos se guardaron Correctamente");
        optionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Guardado Exitoso");
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }                                          


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnGuardar;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnLimpiar;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cmbJornada;
    private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser dcFechaHora;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtApellido;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCargo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtContraseña;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtDocumento;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtDocumentoIngreso;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtJornada;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtNombre;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txthorario;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Archivo persistence**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="TereFoodPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.back.model.Horario</class>
    <class>com.back.model.Usuario</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teresfooduno?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Clase Usuario**

```
@Entity
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
    
    //Atributos
    //Primary key
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id_usuario;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String documento;
    private String cargo;
    private String password;
    
    //relacionamiento horario
    @OneToOne
    private Horario horario;

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public Usuario(int id_usuario, String nombre, String apellido, String documento, String cargo, String password, Horario horario) {
        this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.documento = documento;
        this.cargo = cargo;
        this.password = password;
        this.horario = horario;
    }

    public int getId_usuario() {
        return id_usuario;
    }

    public void setId_usuario(int id_usuario) {
        this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public String getDocumento() {
        return documento;
    }

    public void setDocumento(String documento) {
        this.documento = documento;
    }

    public String getCargo() {
        return cargo;
    }

    public void setCargo(String cargo) {
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Horario getHorario() {
        return horario;
    }

    public void setHorario(Horario horario) {
        this.horario = horario;
    }    
    
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes declarada tu clase `Usuario`? ¿Pusiste en ella la anotación **`@Entity`**?

Comment: Asi es lo mismo con mi otra clase entidad, utilize la annotacion, acabo de subir la clase a la pregunta

Comment: ¿Verificaste que la tabla se llama `Usuario` y que los nombres y tipos de datos de cada columna coinciden? Puede ser conveniente que declares la columna `id_usuario` de tipo `Long` en vez de `int`

Comment: Utilice la anotacion table, me asegure que las tablas tuvieran el mismo nombre y los mismos tipos de datos, cambie el tipo de dato del id a long y aun me aparece el mismo problema.

Comment: En tu archivo `persistence.xml` agrega esto, justo antes de `properties`: **`<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>`**

Comment: Ya encontre el error, mi error era que las clases se estaban compilando con la jdk por defecto 20, y la construccion se llevo acabo con jdk 8. cambie la jdk limpie y construi y el error se solucion,  Muchas gracias por las respuestas

Answer (score 0):

El error era que mis entidades se estaban compilando con la jdk por defecto 20, y la construccion se llevo acabo con jdk 8. cambie la jdk limpie y construi y el error se solucion,  Muchas gracias por las respuestas